# Checking if gpu is integrated or not

Tags: opencl

I couldn't find any query command about device being integrated/embedded in cpu or using system ram or its own dedicated gddr memory? I can benchmark mapping/unmapping versus reading/writing to get a conclusion but that device can be under load at that time and behave wrong and it would add complexity to already complex load balancing algorithm that I'm using.

Is there a simple way to check if a gpu is using same memory with cpu so I can choose directly mapping/unmapping instead of reading/writing?

Edit: there is CL_DEVICE_LOCAL_MEM_TYPE

```
CL_GLOBAL or CL_LOCAL
```

is this an indication of integratedness?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OpenCL 1.x has the device query `CL_DEVICE_HOST_UNIFIED_MEMORY`:

> Is CL_TRUE if the device and the host have a unified memory subsystem
>   and is CL_FALSE otherwise.

This query is deprecated as of OpenCL 2.0, but should probably still work on OpenCL 2.x platforms for now. Otherwise, you may be able to produce a heuristic from the result of `CL_DEVICE_SVM_CAPABILITIES` instead.

Comment: Is deprecation because of that everything will become host unified in future? I'm on opencl 1.2 now and I need this compliant to 2.x later.

Comment: No, not everything will have unified memory with the host in the future. I guess it was deprecated because it was deemed to be under-specified, or because the SVM queries provided more useful information.